# How to make a basic http auth ( Login and Register ) and store the token

Tags: authentication, dart, flutter, dart-html, flutter-dependencies

how are you ?

i have laravel backend with passport auth and now i want to link it with my mobile app in flutter

i want to make the auth but i'm new in flutter and i don't know how to start to do this

first i make my models

this is my first model login.dart

```
class Login {
  final String login;
  final String password;

  Login (this.login,this.password);
}
```

my second model is register.dart

```
class Register {
  final String email;
  final String name;
  final String mobile;
  final String password;

  Register(
    this.email,
    this.name,
    this.mobile,
    this.password,
  );
}
```

and this is User model

```
class User {
  final int id ;
  final int active ;
  final int confirmed ;
  final String mobile  ;
  final String name ;
  final String email ;
  final String confirmation_code ;

 User(this.id,this.active,this.confirmed,this.mobile,this.name,this.email,this.confirmation_code);


}
```

this is my Auth Response Model

```
import './User.dart';

class AuthResponse {
  final String token;
  final User user;

  AuthResponse(
    this.user, this.token
  );


}
```

but now i don't know how to make the auth and link it with these models so can any one help please

thanks

---

New codes

my login page code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../../common/apifunctions/requestLoginAPI.dart';


import 'package:gradient_widgets/gradient_widgets.dart';



class UserLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _UserLoginPage();
  }
}

class _UserLoginPage extends State<UserLoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController _mobileController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _saveCurrentRoute('/UserLogin');
  }

  _saveCurrentRoute(String lastRoute) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.setString('LastScreenRoute', lastRoute);
  }

  void _gloginButton() {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Home');
  }

  void _registerButton() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/UserRegister');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                '/Home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Home');
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/img/LRUI.png'),
              Form(
                child: Container(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Center(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 99.0,
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: _mobileController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'رقم الجوال',
                                hintText: "رقم الجوال يجب أن يكون عشر ارقام",
                              ),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 11.0),
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: _passwordController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'الرقم السري',
                              ),
                              obscureText: true,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 40.0,
                            ),
                            GradientButton(
                              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                colors: const <Color>[
                                  Color(0xff4caf4e),
                                  Color(0xff71c071),
                                ],
                              ),
                              callback: () {
                                SystemChannels.textInput
                                    .invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
                                requestLoginAPI(context, _mobileController.text,
                                    _passwordController.text);
                              },
                              textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
                              shapeRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "دخول",
                              ),
                              increaseHeightBy: 20.0,
                              increaseWidthBy: 140.0,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 35.0,
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text('دخول كضيف'),
                              onPressed: _gloginButton,
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text('تسجيل حساب جديد'),
                              onPressed: _registerButton,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

and this is my my Api function code for request login

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../functions/ saveCurrentLogin.dart';
import '../functions/showDialog.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import '../../Models/Login.dart';
import '../../Models/User.dart';
import '../../Models/AuthResponse.dart';

Future<Login> requestLoginAPI(BuildContext context, String login, String password) async {
  final url = "http://188.166.172.146/Blooming/public/api/login";

  Map<String, String> body = {
    'login': login,
    'password': password,
  };

  final response = await http.post(
    url,
    body: body,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    var token = new AuthResponse.fromJson(responseJson);

    saveCurrentLogin(responseJson);
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/About');
      



    return Login.fromJson(responseJson);
  } else {
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    saveCurrentLogin(responseJson);
    showDialogSingleButton(context, "خطأ", "تأكد من معلومات الدخول", "موافق");

    return null;
  }
}
```

this is my save current login function code

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


import '../../Models/AuthResponse.dart';
import '../../Models/User.dart';

saveCurrentLogin(Map responseJson) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();


  var token = (responseJson != null && !responseJson.isEmpty) ? AuthResponse.fromJson(responseJson).token : "";

  var id = (responseJson != null && !responseJson.isEmpty) ? User.fromJson(responseJson).id : 0;
  var name = (responseJson != null && !responseJson.isEmpty) ? User.fromJson(responseJson).name : "";
  var email = (responseJson != null && !responseJson.isEmpty) ? User.fromJson(responseJson).email : "";
  var mobile = (responseJson != null && !responseJson.isEmpty) ? User.fromJson(responseJson).mobile : "";
  var active = (responseJson != null && !responseJson.isEmpty) ? User.fromJson(responseJson).active : 0;
  var confirmation_code = (responseJson != null && !responseJson.isEmpty) ? User.fromJson(responseJson).confirmation_code : "";
  var confirmed = (responseJson != null && !responseJson.isEmpty) ? User.fromJson(responseJson).confirmed : 0;

  await preferences.setString('token', (token != null && token.length > 0) ? token : "");

  await preferences.setInt('id', (id != null && id > 0) ? id : 0);
  await preferences.setString('name', (name != null && name.length > 0) ? name : ""); 
  await preferences.setString('email', (email != null && email.length > 0) ? email : ""); 
  await preferences.setString('mobile', (mobile != null && mobile.length > 0) ? mobile : ""); 
  await preferences.setInt('active', (active != null && active > 0) ? active : 0);
  await preferences.setString('confirmation_code', (confirmation_code != null && confirmation_code.length > 0) ? confirmation_code : ""); 
  await preferences.setInt('confirmed', (confirmed != null && confirmed > 0) ? confirmed : 0);
  

}
```

this is get token function code

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

getToken() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  String getToken = await preferences.getString("token");
  return getToken;
}
```

this is the new login model

```
class Login {
  final String login;
  final String password;


  Login(this.login, this.password);

  Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : login = json['login'],
        password = json['password'];


}
```

this is auth response model

```
import './User.dart';

class AuthResponse {
  final String token;
  User user;

  AuthResponse({
    this.token,
    this.user,
  });

factory AuthResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
  return AuthResponse(
    token: parsedJson['token'],
    user: User.fromJson(parsedJson['user'])
  );
}
  

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'token': token,
        'user':user,
      };
}
```

this is my User model

```
class User {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String mobile;
  final int active;
  final String confirmation_code;
  final int confirmed;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.mobile,
    this.active,
    this.confirmation_code,
    this.confirmed,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      email: json['email'],
      mobile: json['mobile'],
      active: json['active'],
      confirmation_code: json['confirmation_code'],
      confirmed: json['confirmed'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'email':email,
        'mobile':mobile,
        'active':active,
        'confirmation_code':confirmation_code,
        'confirmed':confirmed,
      };
}
```

Comment: is this code working ?

Answer (score 2):

the best way to do this by using [shared preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences)

- 1 - you need to install dependence (see the link)
- 2 - make your "http" request with your server to get the "auth key"
- 3 - create tow "shared preferences" keys :

and give the first one the name of "auth_key" to store the authentication key
and save the other one as "bool" data type, give it the name "is_login"
now in the main function of the dart, check the parameter "is_login", if its true , countenu to (home page , account ... etc), otherwise take it to the login widget

dart code to set the two keys

```
Future<void> setUserLogin(String auth_token) async{
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setString("auth_token", auth_token);
    pref.setBool("is_login", true);
 }
```

check if login:

```
  Future<bool> isUserLogin() async{
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getBool("is_login");
 }
```

get the auth key:

```
  Future<bool> isUserLogin() async{
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getString("auth_token");
 }
```

logout method

```
  Future<void> logout() async{
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.remove("auth_key");
   pref.remove("is_login");
 }
```

I just give you an example of how to do it, you need to read more about "SharedPreferences" at the link below to know more about
there is another techniques like save data to sql, but its more complicated, and I guess its less secure (cuz there is many root apps working as sqlite browsers)

Comment: i understand your point but i don't how use the sharedpreferences i follow this documentation and the login is worked but now my problem how to keep the user login after i rerun the app 

https://medium.com/flutterpub/organizing-a-token-authentication-with-a-splash-using-flutter-dd6a510338dc

he used here SharedPreferences and its not working with me

Comment: @Abdullah
can you post your code ? (try to abstract it as you can) to help you

Comment: i add all my new codes in the post under New codes line

Comment: am sorry :) i didnt notice
oky lets divide the issue into pieces
at the first run your app , then copy and paste the "run logs" to see
i notice somthing in this part of your code 

`if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    var token = new AuthResponse.fromJson(responseJson);

    saveCurrentLogin(responseJson);
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/About'); << here




    return Login.fromJson(responseJson);
  }`

`Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/About');` well stop the method execution before its end

Comment: your code is a full of bugs !
and unlogical  operations that well make an interrupts in many methods 
you need to dismantling it into  small pieces

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190787/discussion-between-abdullah-and-abdalmonem).

Comment: so can you help me with that to fix these things please .

Comment: waiting for you

Comment: Is there a reason why there's 2 prefs, 1: is_login, 2: auth_key? Can't we just use auth_key?

Comment: @Jessica , yes you can , but boolean comparison expression is more clean and simple, and more understandable specially when you working as a team.

Comment: The package description itself indicates that "this plugin must not be used for storing critical data". It is best fitted for in-app preferences such as turning on/off dark mode.